# "ParticleData[] " command $Failed

Tags: physics, built-in-symbols

I am using Mathematica version 13.2. I am trying to use Mathematica's "ParticleData" command to get the information about the particles directly from PDG. But, whenever I am trying to compile it is showing me an error.  Like:

```
In[6]:= ParticleData["Muon","Mass"]

Out[6]= $Failed
```

I have both the 13.2 and 12.2 version. Both are having the same problem.

But when I am trying this from my another laptop, it is working. I am getting the correct output.

What can be the possible issue? Is there any solution?

Comment: I get a result with version 13.2. This seems to be related to one particular machine rather than to Mathematica itself. Have you tried anything like killing the kernel or restarting Mathematica or even rebooting that machine?